# SQL - Select null as FIELDNAME?

Tags: sql, coding-style

I have come across some code that says

```
select null as UnitCost,
null as MarkUp
```

What exactly is this doing? Is it getting the field names unitcost and markup?

Why would you use "select null as..."?

New to this sorry.

Thanks.

Comment: It returns `null` using `UnitCost` and `MarkUp` field names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That code is aliasing the value `null` and calling it `UnitCost`/`MarkUp`. It is not selecting that column from any available table.

You would usually see this when a statement requires matching column sets, e.g. `union all`.

```
select id, col1, col2, null as UnitCost, null as MarkUp
from table_1
union all
select id, null as col1, null as col2, UnitCode, MarkUp
from table_2
```

Answer (score 3):

Just populate `NULL` to those selected columns

It is useful when you do `Insert...Select`, the Table you are trying to insert may have more columns than the selected table has, for convenience, you could use `select null as col_name` to let the numbers of columns you are trying to insert matches the columns that the target table has.